# Android LoaderManager/Loader code flow

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loader

I was checking the source code for `Loader`/`LoaderManager`. I found the code as follows.

1) `LoaderManager` first calls the method `startLoading`() on the Loader.

2) `startLoading`() in turn calls the `onStartLoading`().

3) `onStartLoading` calls the method `deliverResult`().

Where is the actual background thread started in the `Loader`?
What the code flow tells here is that all the functions are invoked in the UI thread and I could not figure out the background thread starting anywhere.

I want to know how the data is delivered back to the UI thread.

Comment: it is not started in `Loader`, it is started in `AsyncTaskLoader` however

Comment: Can you help me knowing the flow? Not able to get how come the deliverResult() method gets called on the UI thread? And finally onLoadFinished() is called on the UI thread as well?

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.java#87